# What does this sentence mean in polynomial rings?

Tags: ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I have trouble with understanding this sentence in the context of polynomial rings: "We will assume that polynomials satisfy right evaluation. That is, a polynomial can only be evaluated once it is written so that powers of $x$ appear to the right of their coefficients".

I don't underatand this statement. I really appreciate if someone could explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that they allow "scalars" from a noncommutative ring, but some more context would be really helpful.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist yes, coefficients come from a noncommutative ring.

Comment: In fact, the author of the paper (I'm reading) works with polynomials with non-commuting coefficients (Null ideals of subsets of matrix rings over fields by Werner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(clarification from comments: this is from "Null ideals of subsets of matrix rings over fields" by N.J.Werner, and the polynomials are over a noncommutative ring)

They define the evaluation map $ev_r$: $\ldots \to R$ only on polynomials of form $f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ with $f \mapsto \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i r^i$. Unlike the commutative case, this definition need **not** extend to a homomorphism $R[x] \to R$, hence the need for a convention.

Edit: [Noncommutative rings and the evaluation homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647115/)

Comment: Dear @Amateur_Algebraist , Thank you so much for the answer. I got your explanations but could you please explain me these sententes ""We will assume that polynomials satisfy right evaluation. That is, a polynomial can only be evaluated once it is written so that powers of $x$ appear to the right of their coefficients"?

Comment: It means that $x^i a$ $(a\in R)$ can not be evalutaed. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed ,why we can't evaluate polynomials of the form $\sum_i x^i \alpha_i$?

Comment: We can, but the author wants to avoid confusion. Note that just prior they assume that "$x$ commutes with all elements of $R$", so e.g. $ax$ and $xa$ are considered to be the same polynomial. (In other words, the polynomials are uniquely defined by their coefficient lists, as in the commutative case.) But if $a$ is noncentral, these two forms will give different results upon evaluation.

Comment: I got it now. I really appreciate you for your nice explanation.